# Easiest way to build a PostgreSQL tsquery from an array of word prefixes

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

Is there an easy way to generate a `tsquery` from a list of word prefixes?

For example, an array of `{'mat', 'gra'}` would generate a `tsquery` of `'mat:*&gra:*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be done like this:

```
SELECT string_agg(s || ':*', '&')::tsquery
FROM unnest('{mat,gra}'::text[]) AS s;

    string_agg     
-------------------
 'mat':* & 'gra':*
(1 row)
```